# Conditional to toggle button display based on number of items

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

I have an ngFor that display's buttons based on a list of items in HTML. The list can contain 0 or more items. I would like to toggle display of an additional button based on the number of items in that list e.g. if there are 0 items in the list then the button will not display; if there are more than 0 items in the list then the button will display. Here's my code:

```
<div class="panel-body">
     <!--Panel Body-->
     <button *ngFor="#trainingItem of trainingItems" type="button" style="text-align:left; margin-right: 10px;" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
          <strong>Name: </strong> {{trainingItem.Name}}
          <strong>Location: </strong> {{trainingItem.LocationName}}
     </button>

     <!--This is the button I want to toggle based on the number of items-->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="background-color: #323232; margin-top: 10px">Start Training</button>
</div>
```

I know I can handle this by creating a function in my Typescript class that toggles a value based on the number of items in the list, but I would like to handle this entirely on the HTML side and prevent the need to create an entire function in another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to check the arrays length in a `ngIf`:

```
<button *ngIf="trainingItems.length" ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Angular you can display/hide an element with the [NgIf directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)

In your case:

```
<button *ngIf="trainingItems.length" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="background-color: #323232; margin-top: 10px">
  Start Training
</button>
```